# How does fstream work? Memory or file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, iostream

I'm not finding a clear answer to one aspect of the `fstream` object necessary to determine whether it is worth using.  Does `fstream` store its contents in memory, or is it more like a pointer to a location in a file?  I was originally using `CFile` and reading the text into a `CString`, but I'd rather not have the entire file in memory if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fstream` is short for `file stream` -- it's normally a connection to a file in the host OS's file system. (§27.9.1.1/1: "The class `basic_filebuf<charT,traits>` associates both the input sequence and the output sequence with a file.")

It does (normally) buffer some information from that file, and if you happen to be working with a tiny file, it might all happen to fit in the buffer. In a typical case, however, most of the data will be in a file on disk (or at least in the OS's file cache) with some relatively small portion of it (typically a few kilobytes) in the fstream's buffer.

If you *did* want to use a buffer in memory and have it act like a file, you'd normally use a `std::stringstream` (or a variant like `std::istringstream` or `std::ostringstream`).

Comment: So `stringstream` would be preferable for handling a really large text file that I wanted to parse line by line?

Comment: See [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: @JoeMajsterski: no, probably not. A stringstream is typically used as a temporary buffer to (for example) format data before displaying, or to read a line at a time from the file, then use the `stringstream` to parse pieces out of the line.